# Help with unexpected LINQ query results

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have these 4 tables:
[image]

This query

```
    var query = db.Authors
                    .Where(x=> x.ItemAuthors
                        .Any(z=> z.Item.CategoryItems
                            .Any(b=> b.categoryID == 10)))
                    .Select(ci=> new
                {
                    authorText = string.Format("{0} ({1})", ci.text, 
                                                       ci.ItemAuthors.Count()),
                    authorId = ci.authorID
                });
```

Which populates an Authors drop down list which works as expected. The problem is when I try to count the number of items assigned to each author it counts *every* item the author has in the entire items table.

So for example if author one has 10 books total, but only 2 of these books show up in the above query, I still get a count for 10 books. When I bind that same query to a control I get back the correct data, it's just the count operation that won't work correctly.

To reiterate I bound it to a gridview and I only see one book per author, not all of the books the author wrote. So it appears my query should be correct.

**Update:** @Jon Skeet, I wasn't able to use the `let` operator as I'm conditionally building my query. I solved my problem by using the original query to get the count. Here's how I modified my original `Count()` syntax:

```
var query = authors2.Select(x => new
            {

                authorText = string.Format("{0} ({1})",x.text, x.ItemAuthors
                        .Where(qq=> qq.Item.CategoryItems
                            .Any(xt=> xt.categoryID == 10))
                            .Count()),
                authorId = x.authorID

            });
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you're trying to do the count... please show the code which *doesn't* work.

Comment: It's in my select new statement, via `authorText` you have to scroll over.

Comment: Whoops - I hadn't seen it because of the scrolling. It's worth formatting so that we don't have to do that... answering now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `i.Author.ItemAuthors.Count()` which goes straight back to the full table. I suspect you *may* want something like:

```
var query = from ia in db.ItemAuthors
            let count = ia.CategoryItems.Count(t => t.categoryID == 10))
            where count > 0
            select new
            {
                authorText = string.Format("{0} ({1})", i.Author.text, count),
                authorId = i.Author.authorID
            };
```

On the other hand, I would expect that to give one result *per ItemAuthor* which isn't really what you want. If you want a list of *authors*, I'd expect a query starting in the Authors table:

```
var query = from author in db.ItemAuthors
            let count = author.Items
                              .Count(ia => ia.Item.CategoryItems
                                                  .Any(ci => ci.CategoryID == 10))
            select new
            {
                authorText = string.Format("{0} ({1})", author.text, count),
                authorId = author.authorID
            };
```

In other words, for each author, find out how many items have at least one category with ID 10... and then report that many items.

It's somewhat complex because of the various 1-many relationships (each book having potentially multiple authors *and* multiple categories).

Comment: It's saying `author.Items`doesn't contain a definition for count.

Comment: @Nick: What's the type of `author.Items`?

Comment: I believe it should be `Item` which is the items table class. I've updated my code in my question to reflect the authors table.

Comment: @Nick: What you haven't shown is what all the relationships between the classes are. You've shown the tables, but not what the relations are in the entities. But hopefully I've given you enough of a start to figure the rest out yourself.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect how I solved the problem. I will however accept your answer as it got me on the right track. Thanks.